# Create new column for in multiindex dataframe and fillna

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have the following multi-indexed dataframe, generated with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

names = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4']
values = ['x1','x2','x3','x4']
categories = ['y1','y2','y3']

x1 = pd.Series([0, 0, 0], index=categories)

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([names, values]); placeholders = np.zeros((len(names)*len(values), len(categories)))

df = pd.DataFrame(placeholders, index=index, columns=categories)

for i in names:
    for j in values:
        df.loc[i,j] = x1

           y1   y2   y3
Name1 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name2 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name3 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name4 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How would I use a dictionary such as the following to fill the column `y3` corresponding to row `x1` and filling `np.nan` for values for any other rows in the `y3` column or when a given Name (i.e. Name1, Name2, Name3, etc.) is not a key in the dictionary?

```
{'Name1': 54, 'Name3': 50}
```

Expected output (0's could be `np.nan`):

```
           y1   y2   y3
Name1 x1  0.0  0.0   54
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name2 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name3 x1  0.0  0.0   50
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
Name4 x1  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0  0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way is probably to use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
In [31]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({(k,'x1'): {'y3': v} for k, v in d.items()}).T

In [32]: df2
Out[32]: 
          y3
Name1 x1  54
Name3 x1  50

In [33]: df.update(df2)

In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
           y1   y2    y3
Name1 x1  0.0  0.0  54.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name2 x1  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name3 x1  0.0  0.0  50.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name4 x1  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the update df then using `update`

```
d={'Name1': 54, 'Name3': 50}
updatedf=pd.DataFrame(data=list(d.values()),columns=['y3'],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list(d.keys()),['x1','x1']]))
df.update(updatedf)
df
Out[229]: 
           y1   y2    y3
Name1 x1  0.0  0.0  54.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name2 x1  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name3 x1  0.0  0.0  50.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
Name4 x1  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x2  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x3  0.0  0.0   0.0
      x4  0.0  0.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one simple way is using `.loc` indexers:

```
d = {'Name1': 54, 'Name3': 50}

for i in d.keys():
    df.loc[i,'x1']['y3'] = d[i]
```

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do this without any for loops (considering large dataframes)?

Comment: I think a loop is inevitable in this case since we have to update values at multiple indexes. Either we write each line separately or let a loop do the work.

Comment: The dataframe itself is not updating, the values are still NaN